# Definite integral involving possible hypergeometric functions (but can't find one complex enough).

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

- I am working on finding an analytic form of the efficiency for bubble wall collisions, ( physicist not mathematician here ) and so am in need of solving the integral:

$$
\!\!\!\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\!\left(a\xi^{4} + b\xi^{2} -c^{2}\right)^{k/2}\
\left(c\xi + \xi^{2} - f\xi^{3}\right)
^{-\left(k + 2\right)}\
\left(\xi^{6} - g\xi^{4}\right)\mathrm{d}\xi
$$

where $k>0$ to find a solution which depends upon the constants $a, b, c, f$ and $g$.

- I have looked into hypergeometric series such as the integral form of the Appell series and integral form of the Lauricella series and I think the integral I have is something similar however more complex than either of these.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)